# Is it possible to add item to a react array state without re-rendering all items?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am implementing a chat app with react in my UI, I receive `message` via `socket.io`. It is working, but when I add a new one to my array, everything inside it get re-rendered. Is it possible to avoid this behavior ? What I want is to add the new one without re-rendering the precedent ones.

```js
 socket.current.on("getMessage", (message) => {
      setChannelMessages([...channelMessages, message]);
    });
```

Where I am using my `channelMessages` array :

```js
<div className="messages" ref={chatBoxRef}>
        {channelMessages.map((m) => (
          <Message message={m} key={m._id} />
        ))}
        <div ref={scroller}></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please share code where you are doing rerendering

Comment: If you want update state without re-rendering, why define it as state?

Answer (score 4):

*If your component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to `React.memo` for a performance boost. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.* You can read more about it [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), below snippet is an example, You can see that when you add a message, just new message renders.

```js
// I use characters as source of message, just for keep it simple.
let characters ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([]);
  const handleAddMessage = ()=> {
    const newMsg = characters[messages.length];
    setMessages(messages => [...messages, newMsg])
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map(msg => <Message key={msg} message={msg}/>)}
      <button onClick={handleAddMessage}>Add message</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function areEqual({message:prevMessage}, {message}) {
  return message == prevMessage;
}
const Message = React.memo(({message})=> {
  console.log({message});
  return <p>{message}</p>
}, areEqual);

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```